# Google Sheets data to Apple Reminders

Tags: google, reminders

I'd like to transfer a list of names and dates from a Google Sheet into Apple Reminders. The names would be the reminder text, and the date next to each name would become the reminder's alert date.

Example data:

```
| **Name** | **Date** |
| -------- | -------- |
| Episode 1 | 10/1/2024 |
| Episode 2 | 10/8/2024 |
| Episode 3 | 10/14/2024 |
| Episode 4 | 10/18/2024 |
| Episode 5 | 10/19/2024 |
| Episode 6 | 10/30/2024 |
| Episode 7 | 11/4/2024 |
| Episode 8 | 11/8/2024 |
| Episode 9 | 11/10/2024 |
| Episode 10 | 11/13/2024 |
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this in bulk?

I've tried copying and pasting in various forms, tried to convert from Sheet data to Google Tasks as a starting point (to no success), copying the two relevant columns to Numbers first, tried making a Shortcut. I don't even see any way to get the basic list of names into Reminders as separate items.

Comment: Can you add the Shortcut you tried(screenshot)? Should be possible to go from Numbers to Reminder with a shortcut.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to pull any data from a Numbers document in a Shortcut, so I don't have anything to share – I abandoned that after 5 minutes of clueless effort.

Comment: How many lines are in this Sheet? You should be able to copy all of them into the clipboard and then have the shortcut read the clipboard content line by line.